# List Object in C# or Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to store all Customer object attributes to pass selected listitem to display selectedItem information in the detail view. I am successfully getting all Customers information from the webservice.However, in my for loop I am getting the following error.

```
    List <string> list= new List<string>();
    private IEnumerable <IDictionary<string,object>> myData;

    foreach (var customers in myData) {
                list.Add(new Customer((string)customers["CustomerID"],
                    (string)customers ["CompanyName"],
                    (string)customers ["ContactName"],
                    (string)customers ["ContactTitle"],
                    (string)customers ["Address"],
                    (string)customers ["Region"],
                    (string)customers ["PostalCode"],
                    (string)customers ["City"],
                    (string)customers ["Fax"],
                    (string)customers ["Phone"]
                ));

            }
        listView.ItemsSource=list;


public Customer (string customerID,string companyName, 
        string contactName, string contactTitle, string address, string region, string postalCode,string city, string fax, string phone)
    {
        CustomerID = customerID;
        CompanyName = companyName;
        ContactName = contactName;
        ContactTitle = contactTitle;
        Address = address;
        Region = region;
        PostalCode = postalCode;
        City = City;
        Fax = fax;
        Phone = phone;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In the code snippet you posted, it doesn't show the declaration of "list". Code you post the code where you new that up?

Comment: You're right! it was    List <string> list= new List<string>();

Comment: @casillas then you won't be able to add Customer types to a List of strings

Comment: I have fixed List <Customer> list= new List<Customer>();

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you familiarize yourself with C# and OOP in general by reading up on the subject and doing several `"Hello, World!"` type of applications before trying to get into a complex framework like Xamarin.

Comment: HighCore, thanks for the advice. Initially, I was only adding string to my list then I decided to collect object level, then I forgot to changed from string to object. I think every programmer might have this type of basic error.

Comment: HighCore, do you have any recommendation for me to start to become advanced programmer?

Comment: @casillas yes, every programmer (except Jon Skeet, who never made a mistake since he created computer science) does have this type of mistakes, however anyone with a slight amount of OOP knowledge can find the cause and fix it up quickly without posting questions in StackOverflow. My advice still stands.

Comment: Today is Friday and my mind does not functioning as usual. But your advice is valid, I sincerely admit and asking your suggestions since you already passes the steps that I am going to pass.I mostly work on native iOS. And in my spare time  I would like to learn something from Xamarin.

Comment: @casillas - pay attention to the exception information you get, it will usually give enough hint for you to figure out the error. This one says: "Add(string) ... invalid argument ... cannot convert Customer to string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your List type is string. All you have to do is change the List type string to Customer. Like as following

```
List <Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
```

or

```
var list = new List<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I was only adding string to my list then I decided to collect object level, then I forgot to changed from string to object.

```
List <string> list= new List<string>();
```

the following snippet works

```
List <Customer> list= new List<Customer>();
```

I was not paying attention.